# I would like to know why the annotateImage method in imagick module version 3.7.0 only adds the specified text to the image every 3 characters

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

After updating the imagick module, the code that was working before is no longer working properly.

---

PHP code that was working fine until the update

```
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel('gray');

$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

$draw->setFillColor('black');

$draw->setFont('./LINESeedJP_A_OTF_Rg.otf');
$draw->setFontSize(30);

$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->writeImage('./a.png');
```

[Imagick::annotateImage](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/imagick.annotateimage.php)

---

Output result image

[image]

---

Current environment (after update)

imagick module version 3.7.0

PHP7.4

ImageMagick version 6.9.12-73

Comment: Is the Imagick module that you installed now expecting Imagemagick 7 rather than Imagemagick 6?

Comment: I am not particular about the version of Imagick module. After updating from PHP 7.2 to 7.4, this code no longer works correctly!

Comment: But if you do not match the version of Imagemagick to Imagick/PHP, then Imagick will not work correctly.

Comment: I want to match the version of Imagemagick to PHP version 7.4. what is the version of Imagemagick that matches PHP 7.4?

Comment: I do not know. You will have to check the documentation but it really is an issue with matching Imagemagick and Imagick.  Google should help you find needed information. For example, find the PHP 7.4 equivalent of https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php to find the requirement.